# Centrifugal Term

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, centripetal-force, centrifugal-force

I'm studying quantum mechanics with Griffiths (2 nd edition) and I have one question related to the Schrodinger equation in spherical coordinates. In the radial equation:
$$\frac{d}{dr}(r^2\frac{dR}{dr})-\frac{2mr^2}{h^2}[V-E]R=l(l+1)R$$
If we change variables allowing:
$$u(r)=rR(r)$$
we obtain:
$$\frac{-h^2}{2m}\frac{d^2u}{dr^2}+[V+\frac{h^2}{2m} \frac{l(l+1)}{r^2}]u=Eu$$
And the term:
$$[V+\frac{h^2}{2m} \frac{l(l+1)}{r^2}]$$ is the so-called centrifugal term. How could I prove it's a centrifugal and not a centripetal term, for example?

Comment: What do you want to prove here? Nobody is keeping you from calling it a centripetal term instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints:

1. Consider the potential
   $$\tag{1} V_{\rm cf}(r)~:=~\frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \frac{\ell(\ell+1)}{r^2}. $$ 
   For which radius $r$ is the potential (1) smallest? If it smallest for large $r$, it is reasonable to call it a centrifugal (rather than a centripetal) potential.
2. Alternatively, what is the sign of the corresponding force 
   $$\tag{2} F_{\rm cf}~=~-\frac{\partial V_{\rm cf}(r)}{\partial r}~? $$ If $F_{\rm cf}>0$ is positive, it is reasonable to call it a centrifugal (rather than a centripetal) force.